# replacing text in a file with Python

Tags: python, string, file, replace

I'm new to Python. I want to be able to open a file and replace every instance of certain words with a given replacement via Python.  as an example say replace every word 'zero' with '0', 'temp' with 'bob', and say 'garbage' with 'nothing'.

I had first started to use this:

```
for line in fileinput.input(fin):
        fout.write(line.replace('zero', '0'))
        fout.write(line.replace('temp','bob'))
        fout.write(line.replace('garbage','nothing'))
```

but I don't think this is an even remotely correct way to do this.  I then thought about doing if statements to check if the line contains these items and if it does, then replace which one the line contains, but from what I know of Python this also isn't truly an ideal solution.  I would love to know what the best way to do this.  Thanks ahead of time!

Comment: I'll be doing a lot more, but this would give me the best practice for doing this sort of thing.

Comment: In your current approach, every input line is written to the output three times. Is that what you intended to do?

Comment: Also, you're missing an apostrophe after `'bob`.

Comment: thanks about the apostrophe.  and @Junuxx I did not intend to do this (my stupidity is showing).  as mentioned I'm new to Python and from the code experience i have with other languages, reading line by line is standard.  Is this the same with Python or is there a better way to search through a file and replace those particular words with others?

Comment: related: [How to search and replace text in a file using Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/17140886/4279)

Answer (score 84, accepted):

This should do it

```
replacements = {'zero':'0', 'temp':'bob', 'garbage':'nothing'}

with open('path/to/input/file') as infile, open('path/to/output/file', 'w') as outfile:
    for line in infile:
        for src, target in replacements.items():
            line = line.replace(src, target)
        outfile.write(line)
```

**EDIT**: To address [Eildosa's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13089234/replacing-text-in-a-file-with-python/13089373?noredirect=1#comment49137404_13089373), if you wanted to do this without writing to another file, then you'll end up having to read your entire source file into memory:

```
lines = []
with open('path/to/input/file') as infile:
    for line in infile:
        for src, target in replacements.items():
            line = line.replace(src, target)
        lines.append(line)
with open('path/to/input/file', 'w') as outfile:
    for line in lines:
        outfile.write(line)
```

**Edit:** If you are using Python 2.x, use `replacements.iteritems()` instead of `replacements.items()`

Comment: You probably want to move `outfile.write(line)` out of the inner loop...(although this is a literal translation of OP's code)

Comment: What do you really gain here using by using dictionary (as opposed to a list of 2-tuples)?  That's effectively what you get with the `iteritems()` anyway ...

Comment: @Thales: thanks for the bug report (esp. after so long). I've edited my answer

Comment: does this solution really work? the file is overwritten immediately when calling `outfile = open('path/to/input/file', 'w')` so `line` is always empty

Comment: @inspectorG4dget I really don't think it's fixed at all. The line that CodePond.org has mentioned still breaks it

Comment: @user1567453: Look closely at the filepaths, and you'll notice that `infile` and `outfile` refer to two different file paths. This is how it was fixed. Please let me know if I've missed something

Comment: How do I do this using only infile? I don't want a second file

Comment: I think the append needs to be inside the for loop, otherwise lines will only consist of the last line.

Answer (score 10):

If your file is short (or even not extremely long), you can use the following snippet to replace text in place:

```
# Replace variables in file
with open('path/to/in-out-file', 'r+') as f:
    content = f.read()
    f.seek(0)
    f.truncate()
    f.write(content.replace('replace this', 'with this'))
```

Answer (score 7):

I might consider using a `dict` and `re.sub` for something like this:

```
import re
repldict = {'zero':'0', 'one':'1' ,'temp':'bob','garage':'nothing'}
def replfunc(match):
    return repldict[match.group(0)]

regex = re.compile('|'.join(re.escape(x) for x in repldict))
with open('file.txt') as fin, open('fout.txt','w') as fout:
    for line in fin:
        fout.write(regex.sub(replfunc,line))
```

This has a slight advantage to `replace` in that it is a bit more robust to overlapping matches.

Comment: If OP wants to do absolute string replacements, `re` might be overkill… or am I missing something?

Comment: @inspectorG4dget -- If there are overlapping matches, it's necessary.  (`line.replace('bob','robert').replace('robert','foo')`) changes `bob` to `foo` which might not be desireable, but you avoid that with `re`.  Also, since it's all done in 1 go, it might be more efficient (unlikely to matter for small files, but important for big ones).

Answer (score 5):

The essential way is

- `read()`,
- `data = data.replace()` as often as you need and then
- `write()`.

If you read and write the whole data at once or in smaller parts is up to you. You should make it depend on the expected file size.

`read()` can be replaced with the iteration over the file object.

Answer (score 3):

Faster way of writing it would be...

```
finput = open('path/to/input/file').read()
out = open('path/to/input/file', 'w')
replacements = {'zero':'0', 'temp':'bob', 'garbage':'nothing'}
for i in replacements.keys():
    finput = finput.replace(i, replacements[i])
out.write(finput)
out.close
```

This eliminated a lot of the iterations that the other answers suggest, and will speed up the process for longer files.

Comment: But it reads the whole file (and essentially duplicates it for each replacement) -- which is a big downside for large files.

Answer (score 0):

Reading from standard input, write 'code.py' as follows:

```
import sys

rep = {'zero':'0', 'temp':'bob', 'garbage':'nothing'}

for line in sys.stdin:
    for k, v in rep.iteritems():
        line = line.replace(k, v)
    print line
```

Then, execute the script with redirection or piping ([http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Redirection_(computing)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Redirection_%28computing%29))

```
python code.py < infile > outfile
```

Answer (score -1):

This is a short and simple example I just used:

If:

```
fp = open("file.txt", "w")
```

Then:

```
fp.write(line.replace('is', 'now'))
// "This is me" becomes "This now me"
```

Not:

```
line.replace('is', 'now')
fp.write(line)
// "This is me" not changed while writing
```