# TypeError when performing a .open in python

Tags: python

I am trying to open a text file that I have written data to previously in the script and perform multiple find and replaces.  The file is assigned to the variable `text_file` however I get the error:

```
Message File Name Line Position Traceback    <module    C:\temp\download\test.py    41"IOError: [Errno 22] invalid mode ('r') or filename: ""<closed file '20150203-0842.txt', mode 'w' at 0x02D6C5A0>"""
```

I have tried this both in `r` and `w` mode and get the same result.  If I remove the `str` portion of the line I get the error:

`"Message File Name LinePosition Traceback<module> C:\temp\download\test.py 41
TypeError: coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, file found`

Code is:

```
replacelines = open(str(text_file), 'r')

replace = {"u'":'', ' ':'', ']':'', ']':'', "'":''}
for line in replacelines:
    for src, target in replacements.iteritems():
        line = line.replace(src, target)
    replacelines.write(line)
replacelines.close()
```

The code above is from the [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13089234/replacing-text-in-a-file-with-python) however I want do not want to create a a separate file I would like this to remain the same file.

Comment: The Solution can be found [here on SO][1] 


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17140886/how-to-search-and-replace-text-in-a-file-using-python

Answer (score 0):

`open()` expects the *path* to the file as its first argument.  You're passing an actual file object.  Since some file objects don't even have paths (e.g. `io.StringIO`), there's no general way to make this work.  You need to figure out the path to the file and pass that instead:

```
replacelines = open('20150203-0842.txt', 'r')
```

Comment: The path is the location of the script but the file name changes.  I get an invalid syntax error, I need to call the file by a wildcard because the naming convention I am using is based on the date and time I am creating the file `replacelines = open(C:\temp\*.txt, 'r')`

Comment: that was also part of my question...So I can't open a file by assigning it to a variable I have to give the path?

Comment: `open()` does not do glob expansion.  You are opening the file with the literal name `C:\temp\*.txt`... assuming you escaped the backslashes correctly.  Look into `glob` and `os.path`, or on 3.4+, `pathlib`.

Comment: `replacelines = os.open('C:\temp\*.txt', 'w')` throws the error `and integer is required`

Comment: `os.open()` is not, in fact, part of `os.path`.

Comment: I imported `os.path` changed it to `replacelines = "C:\temp\download\*.txt"

replace = {"u'":'', ' ':'', ']':'', ']':'', "'":''}
for path in replacelines:
    for src, target in replace.iteritems():
        line = path.replace(src, target)
    replacelines.replace(line)
replacelines.close()`   Still not working it now hangs on `replacelines.replace(line)` looking for a second argument

Answer (score 0):

Calling `str(text_file)` results in a name of `<closed file '20150203-0842.txt', mode 'w' at 0x02D6C5A0>`, which is an illegal file name. It looks like you expect `str(text_file)` to give you the file name, but it doesn't. Make sure you have the proper file name before opening the file.

Answer (score 0):

From the second error I can see that `text_file` is not a string. The first argument of `open` should be a string containing the path the file, which I don't is the case here.
Just check that, and make sure the (correct) path goes into the first argument and everything is going to work.

Answer (score 0):

If you know that the file in question is a file on disk that you have created, you can retrieve its name from that closed file object you have like this:

```
>>> f = open('myTestFile.txt', 'w')
>>> f.write("foo\n")
>>> f.close()
>>> f
<closed file 'myTestFile.txt', mode 'w' at 0x1010e26f0>
>>> f.name
'myTestFile.txt'
>>> f2 = open(f.name, 'r')
>>> print f2.read()
foo
```

In practice (as others here have already said) it's probably a better idea to store the path & file name separately instead of counting on being able to retrieve it from a closed file object.

Comment: If the file was opened via `open(os.open(something), 'w')`, then this will not work.