# Replace Text with Comma in File With Python

Tags: python

```
#open file and rewrite (comma) to ,
with open('outputFile') as fo:
    fo.write(line.replace("(comma)"," , "))
```

I'm trying to replace the text `(comma)` with a literal `,` within a file. When I run the above code, I get the following error: `io.UnsupportedOperation: not writable`

Any insight as to how to rewrite text within a file would be greatly appreciated.

I've used the below code, and it still won't replace `(comma)` with `,`

`#open file and rewrite (comma) to ,
with open('outputFile.txt', "a+") as fo:
    fo.write(fo.replace('(comma)',','))
fo.close()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to open the file in read/write mode using the 'r+' argument.

Once you read the file contents, clear it using seek(0) and truncate(), and then write the new text.

```
with open('outputFile', 'r+') as f:
    text = f.read()
    f.seek(0)
    f.truncate()
    f.write(text.replace('(comma)', ' , '))
```

Answer (score 1):

You get the "not writeable" error because you need to open the file for writing, done by passing the `mode` argument to `open`:

```
with open('outputFile', "w") as fo:
    fo.write(line.replace("(comma)"," , "))
```

Depending on the behaviour you want, you may want to use a mode other than `"w"`, which truncates the file if it exists. Check out the [Python documentation on `open`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#open) for more details.

If you still get an error then there may be a permissions problem writing to the file.

---

To actually perform a replacement on each line in the file have a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39086/search-and-replace-a-line-in-a-file-in-python) or [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13089234/replacing-text-in-a-file-with-python).

Comment: where does `line` come from?

Comment: It was in the original post.

Comment: From what I understood, OP is reading, replacing, and writing from/to the same file, in which case `line` is undefined.

Comment: Does the new code in my above edit use `fo` and `line` correctly?

Comment: I've added some links answering how to perform a replacement on each line in a file in Python; they answer that question much better than I could.

Comment: This doesn't work, OP wants to both read and write the file from what I gather.

Comment: The question answers why OP was getting the error message that they posted. I've added links to questions that answer how to read and perform replacements on each line in a file.

Answer (score 1):

fileinput will allow you to read/write to the same file pretty easily ...

```
with fileinput.input("out.txt") as fo:
     for line in file:
         print line.replace("(comma)"," , ")
```

Answer (score 0):

Try opening the file in write mode:

```
with open('outputFile', 'w+') as fo:
    fo.write(line.replace("(comma)"," , "))
```