# replacing strings in a file from other txt file with Python

Tags: python, regex

Ive got this code from  [replacing text in a file with Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13089234/replacing-text-in-a-file-with-python)

```
import re
repldict = {'zero':'0', 'one':'1' ,'temp':'bob','garage':'nothing'}
def replfunc(match):
    return repldict[match.group(0)]

regex = re.compile('|'.join(re.escape(x) for x in repldict))
with open('file.txt') as fin, open('fout.txt','w') as fout:
    for line in fin:
        fout.write(regex.sub(replfunc,line))
```

but i cant load the repldict from other txt file.
i've tried with

```
repldict={line.strip() for line in open(syspath+'/rules.txt', 'r')}
```

But it doesn't work.

Comment: How are the data arranged in the file?

Comment: It looks like you're trying to create a dictionary via dictionary comprehension? `repldict={line.strip() for line in open(syspath+'/rules.txt', 'r')}`. This doesn't have key, value pairs that I can see. A guess: You need to load the file, split each line by its delimiter (e.g. a comma, space) and then use indexing to decide which word is the key, and which word is the value that should be used as a substitute for the word you've defined as the key.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the dictionary file has the following simple format:

```
zero 0
one 1
temp bob
garage nothing
```

You can create your dictionary using `split` (not `strip`, `split` without parameters has an integrated `strip` feature somehow) in a generator comprehension which yields tuples (key,value), passed to `dict`:

```
repldict=dict(line.split() for line in open(os.path.join(syspath,"rules.txt"), 'r'))
```

result:

```
{'temp': 'bob', 'one': '1', 'garage': 'nothing', 'zero': '0'}
```

Answer (score 1):

Considering that your 'rules.txt' file looks like:

```
zero:0
one:1
temp:bob
garage:nothing
```

then:

```
with open(syspath+'/rules.txt', 'r') as rules:
    repldict={}
    for line in rules:
        key, value = line.strip().split(':')
        repldict[key] = value
```