# How can I change the output file name without reading in the whole file?

Tags: python, import, fwrite

So, I am using this to replace a text `odirx` in a file and then writing it out to another file. But I would like the output file name to be `sm_0120.txt` instead of `sm_template2.txt` as well.

```
replacements = {'odirx':'0120'}

with open('/dir/sm_template.txt') as infile, open('/dir/sm_template2.txt', 'w') as outfile:
    for line in infile:
        for src, target in replacements.items():
            line = line.replace(src, target)
        outfile.write(line)
```

How can I do this?

It could write out the entire file after reading in, but I wanted to do this without reading in the whole file

Related: 
[replacing text in a file with Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13089234/replacing-text-in-a-file-with-python)

**TRIAL**

**I AM OKAY WITH READING IT IN IF THAT IS MY ONLY CHOICE**

```
replacements = {'odirx':'0120'}

with open('/dir/sm_template.txt') as infile, open('/dir/sm_template2.txt', 'w') as outfile:
        for line in infile:
            for src, target in replacements.items():
                line = line.replace(src, target)
            lines.append(line)
            outfile = os.path.join(os.path.normpath(os.getcwd()+os.sep+"sm_"+os.sep+target+os.extsep+"txt"))
```

How can I write it out?

Comment: use os.rename for changing the file once you save it

Comment: He wants two copies of the file if I understand correctly

Comment: @jmercouris Yes! Please see my edit "TRIAL"

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately you'll have to write a new file since you are modifying it as part of a stream, there is no way around that

to clarify though, there do exist functions for copying files https://stackoverflow.com/a/123212/1699398

Answer (score 0):

Use os.rename:

```
os.rename('/dir/sm_template2.txt', '/dir/sm_0120.txt')
```