# Editing a column by a multiplier, and then replacing the column with the multiplier and saving the file as a new .txt file -python

Tags: python

So I have a file that looks like this

mass (GeV)   spectrum (1-100 GeV)

10  0.06751019803888393

20  0.11048827045815585

30  0.1399367785958526

40  0.1628781532692572

I want to multiply the spectrum by half or any percentage, then create a new file with the same data, but the spectrum is replaced with the new spectrum multiplied by the multiplier

```
DM_file=input("Name of DM.in file: ") #name of file is DMmumu.in
print(DM_file)
n=float(input('Enter the percentage of annihilation: '))
N=n*100
pct=(1-n)

counter = 0
with open (DM_file,'r+') as f:
    with open ('test.txt','w') as output:
        lines=f.readlines()
        print(type(lines))
        Spectrumnew=[]
        Spectrum=[]


        for i in range(8,58):
            single_line=lines[i].split("\t")
            old_number = single_line[1]
            new_number = float(single_line[1])*pct

            Spectrumnew.append(new_number)
            Spectrum.append(old_number) 
            f.replace(Spectrum,Spectrumnew)
            output.write(str(new_number))
```

The problem I'm having is f.replace(Spectrum,Spectrumnew) is not working, and if I were to comment it out, a new file is created called test.txt with just Spectrumnew nothing else. What is wrong with f.replace, am I using the wrong string method?

Comment: I  would recommend to use a csv parser. Delimiter is a space in your case. Docs: https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`replace` is a function that works on strings.  `f` is not a string.  (For that matter, neither is `Spectrum` or `Spectrumnew`.)

You need to construct the line you want in the output file as a string and then write it out.  You already have string output working.  To construct the output line, you can just concatenate the first number from the input, a tab character, and the product of the second number and the multiplier.  You can convert a number to a string with the `str()` function and you can concatenate strings with the `+` operator.

There are several more specific answers on this site already that may be helpful, such as [replacing text in a file with Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13089234/replacing-text-in-a-file-with-python).